# How can i build the tree diagram?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, qtree, pst-tree

[image]

I   want    as    in    the    picture

Comment: Ti*k*Z has a `trees` library. `tikz-qtree` or `forest` are Ti*k*Z-based tree-drawing packages. Or the pstricks stuff. Most of this is in the tags you added, so you seem to know where to start. Why did you add `sticky-labels` and `ticks`, though?

Comment: Questions on this site should not just post an image and ask for code. Please include code for a minimal working (or non-working) example (MWE or MnWE) and ask about a specific problem you want help with. There are *numerous* examples of trees on the site. Please start by looking at those or the package documentation. If you get stuck, post your code and a specify question.

Comment: I want cookies.

Answer (score 1):

minimal effort question ⇒ minimal effort answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[tree layout,grow=right,fresh nodes] {
    "" -- {
      "1" -- {
        "3 (1,3)",
        "5 (1,5)" 
      },
      "2" -- {
        "3 (2,3)",
        "5 (2,5)" 
      },
      "4" -- {
        "3 (4,3)",
        "5 (4,5)"
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]